# The approximate probability that the board will not have a cards for a possible straight for any player?

Tags: texas-hold-em

For example, board will be like:

A 2 6 J 9

No one player can't collect straight with their any two hand cards.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the best way to calculate this, but I did a brute-force count.

I examined if any 2-card hands when added to the 2598960 possible 5-card boards formed a straight.  Some of these 2-card hands are impossible (such as having pocket aces when 4 aces are on the board).  But I think that there is no case where this creates a straight when one is impossible, so I didn't bother to exclude them.

If so, there are 658480 possible boards that cannot allow a straight to be completed with any 2-card hand.  Or a bit over 25%.

Also this count ignores hands that would not be classified as a "straight" for other reasons.  For instance, some of these straights are really a straight flush.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful